# Blood group diet

Tags: fat-loss

Has anyone tried the blood group diet. I have been thin all my life, for the past 6 months, I have worked out hard in the gym and eaten well. Results are great. But along with muscle, I have also gained fat. I have been very strict with my diet, absolutely no processed food, no sugar, lots of vegetables, nuts and fruits, chicken and eggs.

Based on the blood group diet, I should be avoiding bananas, whey and dairy (which I have been consuming). I'm going to try that for a couple of weeks. Just want to check if anyone has tried this type of diet and seen any results.

Thanks

Comment: Care to explain what the reasons for avoiding those products?

Comment: Based on the blood group diet. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_type_diet Also please google for the term, you'll find a ton of information.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_type_diet#Scientific_criticism - "blood type astrology"

Comment: If you want others to help you, pointing them to Google isn't the way to go. You put in some effort then we will as well.

Comment: Sorry Ivo, I did mention the wikipedia link. Here's another one http://www.apricotseeds.com.au/Type-A-Blood-Group.pdf This is just a summary from Adamo's book http://www.amazon.com/Eat-Right-Your-Type-Individualized/dp/039914255X/ref=pd_sim_b_2

Comment: @Arun, perhaps I should have been more clear, but I wanted you to explain where this diet is based upon, because as @Megasaur points out this diet is very controversial (scientifically speaking). So if you explain why it claims it works, we can discuss those attributes as considered healthy or not. Simply polling whether others liked the diet is 'not a real question'.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a legitimate question according to the site guidelines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Blood Type Diet is pseudoscientific hogwash. The ideas were published in a 1994 book by Peter D'Adamo. While some of his advice may be beneficial, such as avoidance of whey protein or wheat, the logic behind it is entirely fabricated and fraudulent. I will list a few of the bogus claims he makes and you can judge if he knows what he is talking about.

D'Adamo claims that type O is the original blood type in humans, and other types evolved as humans adopted different lifestyles (e.g., pastoral, agricultural). In 1990 “Evolution of Primate ABO Blood Type Genes and Their Homologous Genes,” Saitou and Yamamoto state [p. 405] that type A was the first to evolve in early primates. This happened long before humans even existed, let alone developed agriculture or other lifestyles.

There is no correlation between the blood types found in native populations in the world and their lifestyle. Alaskan Inuit hunter gatherers who have never practiced animal husbandry or agriculture have a higher frequency of Type A blood than Type O. Same for Blackfoot Indians (Niitsítapi) who were nomadic buffalo hunters. On the other hand, Cantonese Chinese who have farmed rice for millenia have more Type O blood than Type A.